# MVC - setting up Create.cshtml with related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm quite new to C#, MVC and EF and I've hit a problem I don't seem o be able to resolve.

I'm trying to update the Create.cshtml view so that it shows/lists the itemName rather than itemID where the Item Name is in a different table.

Heres parts of my code so far:

Models:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CIMSTest.Models
{
    public class DirectActivityItem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int DirectTypeID { get; set; }
        public string ActivityName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateActivityCreated { get; set; }
        public bool ActivityLive { get; set; }
        public ICollection<DirectActivityGroup> DirectActivityGroups { get; set; }
        public DirectType DirectType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CIMSTest.Models
{
    public class DirectType
    {
        public int DirectTypeID { get; set; }
        public string DirectTypeName { get; set; }
        public bool DirectTypeLive { get; set; }
        public ICollection<DirectActivityItem> DirectActivityItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller (Create):

```
       public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["DirectTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.DirectTypes, "DirectTypeID", "DirectTypeID");
            return View();
        }


        // POST: DirectActivityItems/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,DirectTypeID,ActivityName,DateActivityCreated,ActivityLive")] DirectActivityItem directActivityItem)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(directActivityItem);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["DirectTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.DirectTypes, "DirectTypeID", "DirectTypeID", directActivityItem.DirectTypeID);
            return View(directActivityItem);
        }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@model CIMSTest.Models.DirectActivityItem

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>DirectActivityItem</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DirectTypeID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="DirectTypeID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DirectTypeID"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ActivityName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ActivityName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ActivityName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DateActivityCreated" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DateActivityCreated" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DateActivityCreated" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
                <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="ActivityLive" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ActivityLive)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

As you can see the Direct ActivityItem table contains the DirectTypeID, but on the Create page for this I want to list the DirectTypeNames from the DirectType table and not the ID as users won't know what the ID's are.

If anyone can provide any information it would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
ViewData["DirectTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.DirectTypes, "DirectTypeID", "DirectTypeID");
```

to this:

```
ViewData["DirectTypeID"] = new SelectList(_context.DirectTypes, "DirectTypeID", "DirectTypeName");
```

You'll want your view model returning the DirectTypeID since that will be how you best resolve the relationship, but the third parameter tells the SelectList what to display for each selection.